# how to get and send hebrew?

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I write code in google app to send string from my google Spreadsheet to my python
I send the string with this code

```
function doPost(e)
.....
var rows=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   var list=rows[1][0];
  for (var r =2 , l =rows.length  ; r < l; r++) {
    list = list + "," + rows[r][0]
  }
  return list
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(list)
}
```

the data on Spreadsheet is in hebrew.
in python I get unclear letters (gibberish)

the code in python

```
check=requests.post(url)
check.text
```

What do I need to change to get clear Hebrew?

if i print hebrew - not from the requests.post, i saw hebrew

Comment: Sounds like an encoding/decoding issue. Can you post a sample of your response?

Comment: if i copy past i saw hebrew. in the cml i don't saw hebrew.